# Public/Desktop ACL entries reset

Tags: windows-10, permissions, desktop

I tried to reduce the need for administrative privs on Windows 10 domain members. One common action people want to do is to delete desktop icons from the shared public desktop (because of stupid software installer). So I added a Local group where I add the owner users (kind of similar to power users) and add that group with a “delete allow” ACL entry on the public desktop folder. This works (somewhat, you have to open the folder and can’t delete the icons directly on your desktop but it is a alternative for [this question](https://superuser.com/q/310581/86524)) but the ACL seems to be reset regularly (the ACE for this local group with the Allow permission is removed).

Seems like something reset the folder permissions and I am not sure what it is. We dont think it’s a group policy.. at least not intentional. Is there a permission template in Windows for that folder to adjust as well? (And what triggers its application?)

This is part of the script (which works, but the setting gets lost after a few days):

```
$PublicDesktop = "$env:Public\Desktop"
$localowneraccount = "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$localowners"
$acl = Get-Acl $PublicDesktop
$t = $null
$t = $acl.Access | where { $_.IdentityReference -eq $localowneraccount -and $_.FileSystemRights.ToString() -imatch "Delete"}
if ($t -eq $null) {
  $_perms = "$([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Delete),$([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles)"
  $_inherit = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit+[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit
  $_propagate = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::InheritOnly
  $_allow = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
  $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($localowneraccount, $_perms, $_inherit, $_propagate, $_allow)
  $acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
  $acl | Set-Acl $PublicDesktop -ErrorAction Stop
  Write-Host "Added Delete permission for Public Desktop to Group=<$localowners>"
} else {
  Write-Verbose "Public Desktop delete permission already granted to Group=<$localowners>"
}
```

Comment: "but the ACE seems to be reset regularly." - What exactly is the ACE in this context?

Comment: @Ramhound I added the full code

Comment: You should indicate which permissions are being reset exactly.  You should also clarify if you mean ACE or ACL by editing your question.  I have no idea what ACE stands for.  I know what ACL stands for.  How often i the script being ran exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound the complete entry for this group is removed. An ACE is one entry in an ACL.

Comment: Workaround, but not elegant: have your script run as a Scheduled Task, or on boot.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yeah, I actually am more curious about what’s going on. I can alternatively schedule the deletes priveledged and don’t need the permission, but it’s still strange where this is coming from. I like to understand the permission template system better. (If this is what it is causing it)